# Can not change argument value in block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I came across a problem when using block. Look at the simple example I created :

[image]

Say , I have a global variable, and I want to change its value by passing it as an argument of the function "requstWithArg:". But the value is changed in a block. So, an error happened  , because I can not declare the argument to be a __block type.

How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

well type `id` is simply a pointer to an object, so why cant you declare a new variable above the block declaration like this: `__block  id myVar = arg;`

so you would have:

```
__block id myVar = arg;
void (^blk)(void) = ^(void){myVar = [NSString string];};
```

I cant test this right now, but does it not work for some reason?

However, I'm also a bit confused at what exactly you are tying to do, this looks like a nonsensical design to me. It looks like you are taking some arbitrary object pointer and clobbering it with a new `NSString`... am I missing something?